# How to let an activity intent to itself?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, mobile, mobile-development

Can an activity do an intent to itself? I have an activity created, it's called activity_beautician_profile. This activity has an edit button, which lets the user edit their profile. So I was planning on disabling the EditText at first and then enabling it when the user clicks the edit button.

I added an android:onClick="onClick" in the edit button already

**This is my code so far:**

```
public class BeauticianProfile extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnedit;
    EditText t1, t2, t3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_beautician_profile);

        final EditText t1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        final EditText t2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
        final EditText t3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        final EditText t4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gender);

        //so that i can pass my values from the sign-Up page to this page
        t1.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("name"));
        t2.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("mobile"));
        t3.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("email"));
        t4.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("gender"));
    }

    public void onClick (View v) {
        if (v.getId() == btnedit.getId()) {
            t1.setFocusable(true);
            t2.setFocusable(true);
            t3.setFocusable(true);
        }
    }
}
```

My apps stops when i click the edit button

Comment: Put logcat error also

Comment: i put logcat now but i dont understand what it says. the messages are all in colored black but this is the message that was in a different color W/View: dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring it's colored blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`btnedit` is null as you haven't implemented it

Comment: im sorry im fairly new to coding. im not quite sure by what you mean as "implement" should it be like this then??

btnedit.setOnclickListener(new OnClickListener(){
//then put my onClick code that i did earlier
)};

like that?

Comment: Your `btnedit` is null. You haven't called `btnedit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.someId);`